# Make a Unique PHP Array based on a section of the value?

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I am working on a WordPress site where the client has uploaded thousands of photos to Flickr and now want me to move them all back into WordPress and associate them with there proper posts.

Even though there are thousands of images, there is really only about 50 unique images, all the other versions are the same image but uploaded to a different location on Flickr or a slightly different size or name.

In helping me track down all the unique images, based on a list like below, that part I have highlighted, I need to pull every record into a PHP array, the catch is the part I have highlighted, is what I want to make sure is `UNIQUE` among all records in the array.

Any help in taking an existing PHP ARRAy that has every record and making the array only show unique values based on that part of the Value string?

Is this a Regular Expressions use case?

If it used Regex or similar I think a pattern it could look for is `/4485116555_` `/` followed by `10 digits` and then followed up with a `_`

Appreciate any help in getting me 1 step closer to my goal, this is just 1 piece of the big puzzle.

[image]

```
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4042/4485116555_19cc0eaa85.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2703/4485767454_77476dbdd0.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4008/4485116637_ff085b0ab2.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4002/4485766896_af83d349c4.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4037/4485766950_50d5739344.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2785/4485116905_1fa0e2ea6c.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4052/4704387613_77542dac2e.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2734/4485767622_7b04c3bd3e.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4037/4485767292_1a37fe6c57.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4038/4485116955_f9c47672c3.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4051/4485115681_6d7419a00b.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2753/4485116095_30161a56bb.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4123/4831194968_3977dff9dc.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4054/4538941056_cda5a8242d.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2091/4515081466_43cd1624ce.jpg
http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2684/4485766664_3bb9dd9c80_m.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4010/4485115557_a38aac0e1f.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4055/4485115633_19e6e92276.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4045/4485766710_08691e99ed_m.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4024/4485115521_9ab2a33d53_m.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4048/4505577820_81ce080f2a_t.jpg
http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5294/5389182894_920a54ce97_m.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4152/5073487038_5bdb9e3cbc_t.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4024/4485115401_67a8957509_m.jpg
http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4062/4485766842_2209843592_m.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ids = array(); // Where we will keep our unique list of IDs

$lines = array(/* your list of URLs here */);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  preg_match(
    '|^http://[A-Za-z0-9\\.]+/[0-9]+/([0-9]+)_[a-f0-9]+.*\\.jpg$|',
    'http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4054/4538941056_cda5a8242d.jpg',
    $matches
  );
  echo $matches[1]; // 4538941056 
  $ids[] = $matches[1]; // Push that into the IDs array
}
$ids = array_unique($ids);
print_r($ids);
```

Comment: That doesn't work as a PART of the string is unique but not the whole string

Comment: @jasondavis, I just caught that and edited my answer.  RegEx is a good choice here.  Parse the ID out first, then add that to the array.  You can step through the array and filter with `array_filter()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php, but this seems easier to me.

Comment: Yeah I guess the part I need help with is getting that ID out of the value part

Comment: Yeah RegEx is a pain, Here is yours in action http://bit.ly/19edWs3 it does match the whole value but I'm not sure if that will let me extract just the ID portion out of it.. Thanks for the effort

Comment: @jasondavis, It does... hence the parenthesis.  Hang on, let me work up a more complete code example for you.

Comment: @jasondavis, Check my last edit.  Untested, but should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get your ID Portion

```
$url = 'Your image url';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$pathFragments =  explode('/', $path);
$end = end($pathFragments);

$id = substr($end,0,9);
```

And then run array_unique() to get the unique values.